# Restart thread if not able to upload

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I am using threadpool to upload using S3. However, I suspect that sometimes one thread might fail. Therefore, I want to restart the thread that has failed. I want some pointers on how can i achieve this:

```
pool = ThreadPool(processes=10)
pool.map(uploadS3_helper, args)

def uploadS3_helper(args):
    return uploadS3(*args)


def uploadS3(myfile, bucket_name, key_root, path_root, use_rel, define_region):
    if define_region:
        conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_KEY,
                        host='s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com')
    else:
        conn = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id=S3_ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=S3_SECRET_KEY)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    print key_root + myfile
    print path_root
    print os.path.join(path_root, myfile)
    if use_rel:
        bucket.new_key(key_root + myfile).set_contents_from_file(open(os.path.join(path_root, myfile[1:])))
    else:
        bucket.new_key(key_root + myfile).set_contents_from_file(open(path_root))
```

Comment: I don't understand.  If the code in the thread detects a failure, why can it not retry itself?  What is the point of another line of execution if it cannot do its work on its own and needs to to be continually micro-managed by another thread?

Comment: Suppose S3 rejects a connection during the execution of a particular thread and one file remains to upload , I want to retry until the upload is complete.

Comment: OK, so it fails.  Sleep a bit, loop back, retry to connect.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Martin James comment: consider a "[retry decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry)".  Add the linked code to your project, flag the `uploadS3` function, and it'll try to upload multiple times, waiting longer after each failure.